# Simulating in LTspice with LM1875

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, simulation, ltspice

I am trying to simulate a simple amplifier with LTspice using LM1875 which I have imported. Whenever I try to simulate, it ends up giving me an error message.

[image: circuit]

```
Circuit: * C:\Users\Ulv\Documents\LTspiceXVII\Simprosjekt.asc

ERROR: Node U1:14 is floating and connected to current source G:U1:U2:R11
ERROR: Node U1:16 is floating and connected to current source G:U1:U3:RES
ERROR: Node U1:U_TF:VP1 is floating and connected to current source G:U1:U_TF:P1
ERROR: Node U1:U_TF:VP2 is floating and connected to current source G:U1:U_TF:P2
ERROR: Node U1:U_TF:VP3 is floating and connected to current source G:U1:U_TF:P3
ERROR: Node U1:U_TF:VP4 is floating and connected to current source G:U1:U_TF:P4
ERROR: Node U1:U_TF:VZ1 is floating and connected to current source G:U1:U_TF:Z1
ERROR: Node U1:U_TF:VZ2 is floating and connected to current source G:U1:U_TF:Z2
ERROR: Node U1:U_TF:VZ3 is floating and connected to current source G:U1:U_TF:Z3
ERROR: Node U1:U_TF:VZ4 is floating and connected to current source G:U1:U_TF:Z4
ERROR: Node U1:18 is floating and connected to current source G:U1:U_TF:Z5

WARNING: Less than two connections to node OUTPUT.  This node is used by R§SPEAKER.
Direct Newton iteration failed to find .op point.  (Use ".option noopiter" to skip.)
Starting Gmin stepping
Gmin = 10
Gmin = 1.07374
vernier = 0.5
vernier = 0.25
vernier = 0.125
vernier = 0.0625
Gmin = 0.995033
vernier = 0.03125
vernier = 0.015625
vernier = 0.0078125
vernier = 0.00390625
vernier = 0.00195313
Gmin = 1.00079
vernier = 0.000976563
vernier = 0.000488281
Gmin = 0
Gmin stepping failed

Starting source stepping with srcstepmethod=0
Source Step = 3.0303%
vernier = 0.25
Source Step = 7.57576%
Source Step = 15.1515%
Source Step = 22.7273%
Source Step = 30.303%
Source Step = 37.8788%
vernier = 0.375
Source Step = 48.8636%
Source Step = 60.2273%
Source Step = 71.5909%
Source Step = 82.9545%
Source Step = 94.3182%
vernier = 0.5625
Source stepping succeeded in finding the operating point.


Date: Mon Apr 20 16:35:01 2020
Total elapsed time: 2.934 seconds.

tnom = 27
temp = 27
method = modified trap
totiter = 170928
traniter = 161335
tranpoints = 29394
accept = 21505
rejected = 7889
matrix size = 72
fillins = 114
solver = Normal
Thread vector: 7.8/5.0[2] 1.7/1.7[1] 2.7/2.6[1] 0.6/0.8[1]  2592/500
Matrix Compiler1: 8.38 KB object code size  1.8/0.8/[0.5]
Matrix Compiler2: 7.38 KB object code size  1.3/1.0/[0.3]
```

You can find circuit I'm working on here:
https://github.com/ulvehender/elektro/blob/master/Simprosjekt.rar

Comment: You need to include your circuit schematic and an exact copy of the error message **in your question**.

Comment: Have you tried a different op-amp to prove that it is the op-amp model that is at fault?

Comment: @Andy aka LM1875 is a "complete" 20W audio amp, not an opamp. Still highly suspect the model.

Comment: @TylerStone It wouldn't matter if it's a black hole creator, replacing it with another opamp works. As for which other model to use, that's up to OP's discretion. That's why I ended up my answer with "*your* (OP) *choice about what to do next*".

Comment: @a concerned citizen LM1875 is not an opamp.

Comment: @TylerStone Somehow I missed this reply then. If you look at its internal schematic, it's a power opamp, and since in SPICE you can feed kA in a short circuit, you can replace the LM1875 with some other opamp or concoction that has similar characteristics. After all, OP's schematic doesn't look like it's serious business, more like "let's see what comes out", which means using the `UniversalOpamp2` would be "just fine(TM)".

Answer (score 1):

The LM1875 is old enough to have a defective sim model made before simulator software was made.
I see a couple of errors on your schematic:
[image: LM1875]

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad model, full of behavioural conditionals and `limit()`s which bring discontinuities in the derivative. Many capacitors are directly connected across current sources which act as integrators, probably, or try to smooth out the discontinuities, but which have no parallel resistor to provide a DC path to ground. It's begging for "timestep too small" errors and outputs swinging to kV or more (which is what happens in my case).

There's also an unneeded `.END` at the end of the block of text which cancels any attempt to replace the faulty opamp with one from the internal database, with the error: `unknown subcircuit ...`. The `.END` is a keyword that signifies the end of all the netlist. Anything added after it is simply discarded, for example adding an opamp causes the adjacent `.lib` call to fail, since it falls outside the scope of the netlist.

If you correct `.END` into an `.ENDS`, suitable for the end of a subcircuit definition, it complains about a stray `.ENDS`. Which means it's safe to be deleted.

The solution is to replace the opamp witn another, preferably a working one. Once you delete it and replace the faulty opamp, you'll see the simulation flying. For example, placing the first available opamp in LTspice's library, `AD549`, makes the simulation run. Three more random attempts, `AD8565`, `LT1022`, `LT1369`, all work (though the `AD8565` is slower, the model might not be quite so well made). Your choice about what to do next.